# How to Get Index of a Selected Item From List Object

Tags: typescript

I need to get index of a selected object from list, in my code:

```
let index = this.List.map(function (x) { return x.ID }).indexOf(this.Item);
```

Every time I'm mapping, is there any other solution for this without mapping.

Comment: And how your `List` looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `findIndex`.

```
let index = this.List.findIndex(function (x) { return x.ID == this.Item });
```

With `arrow function.`

```
let index = this.List.findIndex(x => x.ID == this.Item);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use lodash `findIndex` method like this :

```
let index = _.findIndex(this.List, item => item.ID === this.Item.ID)
```

See [documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#findIndex) for more info.